# Insert data through another controller or model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am not sure If i am asking the right questions but I think what I am trying to figure out is simple.

I am making a time sheet program where TimeSheet belongs_to :user and has_many :entries.  Entries belongs_to :time_sheet.

I am working in my time_sheet view on the new/create action.  I am trying to make new entries in the Entries model and have them show up on the corresponding time sheet.

This is what I am working with so far.

Here is my new view:

```
<%= form_for @current.each do |f| %>

<table summary="Subject form fields">
  <tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_name) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Order Number</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:order_number) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Time In</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:time_in) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Time Out</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:time_out) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-buttons">
  <%= submit_tag("Add Entry") %>
</div>
```

This is my time sheet controller:

```
 class TimeSheetController < ApplicationController
  def delete
  end

  def edit
  end

  def index

  @time_sheets = TimeSheet.all
  end

  def new
    if current_user
    @current = User.find(current_user).time_sheets.entries
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'

  end
end


  def show
    @current = User.find(params[:id]).time_sheets.entries
  end
end
```

FYI I am completely new to rails and I am still learning how to name things correctly and things like that.  Any help pointing me in the correct direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try googling for nested forms in rails. It allows you to do that kind of stuff. It's easy to setup and implement. There are lots of blog posts and screencasts on this topic as well.